# Can I install a damaged disc to hard disk without damaging it any further?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a game disc (specifically Black Ops 2) that has a few scratches on it. I can still play in multiplayer mode with it, but sometimes I get disc load errors.

I'm considering copying the disc to hard disk to avoid those errors, but is it safe to do, or will the copy process damage the disc even further?

Comment: "Crack" as in "the disk has light scratches" or as in "you can drive a needle through the disc without damaging it further"?

Comment: Try it and see? I'd guess not, since it can't copy data from the disc if the disc is busted. Perhaps borrow a good disc from a friend to install, then it should work.

Comment: light scratche but on cracked at the hole in middle of disc i can still play it but it will read a error every once in a while but yea still works for online use

Comment: ok thanx i just wanted to kno other peoples opinion first before i tried. trying not to mess it up furthur and i kno where to borrow a good disc from

Comment: Edited the question to improve its quality. I believe it's a valid question, just poorly worded.

Comment: Well I wouldn't know about if it works with xbox, but in the early days when a cd's had scratches on it, and wouldn't install or wouldn't start up anymore. You could either copy all files to your drive and install it via that way, or you could make a copy of the disk. And it would behave like new most of the time.

Comment: @AASxRaGeXx I had a small crack in the center of my disc too, I don't have the drive that the disc broke in, so Install the disc and it will read it every now and again but remember, you're on a finite amount of time before the disc decides to go lemming.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I did this once, with Fallout 3, but it turned out that the problem was with the drive and not the disc so I can't make any guarantees.

Installing to the HDD might work. There's no rush during an install, so the Xbox360 can re-read multiple times without killing a running process. You have nothing to lose, so I recommend trying it.

If the install fails you can borrow a clean disc to install, and the Xbox360 will be able to recognize the broken one so you can play the game after giving the clean copy back. This is what I was doing for some time when my drive was having trouble reading (that is, I could play games installed before the problem started).

Answer (score 0):

You can install the game to your Xbox's HDD. As long as your game isn't too damaged and the Xbox can recognize it's the game that is installed on your HDD, you can play it without reading the content on the disc.

My Halo 3 Collectors edition came with a crack in the middle of the disc (bad enough to warrant a full exchange), right over the middle of the "shiny" part. I installed (not copied) it onto my HDD, and even with the disc in that condition it still plays (by reading off the HDD).

The scratches on your disc are probably caused by one of two things:

1. Laser node too high and scratches your disc.
2. Handling of the disc.

Either way, installing to your drive should not damage it more than it already is. My busted Halo 3 disc didn't explode in the drive, so I'm guessing you should be ok. Be warned that your mileage may vary.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try looking online for a hard drive installment you can download, extract and move to xbox via usb. No reason it couldn't work, it's just finding it thats the trouble. I wouldn't know what you'd even search for though, hard drive installment for xbox 360 maybe? Probably not lol, but all it would take is someone to upload it to say like mediafire or something and download it from there, I could do with a few of those myself lost some good games to the dreaded laser burn.. It's not too bad i've seen much worse I know it would work if I had the installment not all my friends have xbox, its more ps3 where i'm at